# Upper and Lower bounds of Sum of Sum-of-Divisors

Tags: calculus, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I want to know an upper bound of this function: $$\sum_{n\le x}\sigma(n)$$ where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors.

Are there any known upper and lower bounds?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an asymptotic, meaning the ratio between them converges to $1$ as $x\to\infty$. That means it may very well be neither an upper or lower bound, even eventually - sometimes estimates can oscillate above and below the true value infinitely often. (I have no idea if that's the case here, it could actually be a bound too.)

Comment: @runway44 Ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sum actually has a surprisingly nice upper and lower bound. It turns out

$$\frac{x(x+1)}{2} \le \sum_{n\le x}\sigma(n) \le x^2$$

You can verify this for yourself with a python script such as [this one](https://repl.it/@AnirudhAwesome/FaithfulUnfinishedTags)

Now let's discuss how I arrived at these bounds:

We can reframe this problem to make it a little simpler to think about. Instead of adding up $\sigma(i)$ for every $i$ from $1$ to $x$, we can instead try to find out how many times each **factor**(from $1$ to $x$) is counted, and use this to find our answer.

For example in the case of $x=9$ we know:

> $1$ will be counted $9$ times (at $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$)
>
> $2$ will be counted $4$ times (at $2,4,6,8$)
>
> $3$ will be counted $3$ times (at $3,6,9$)
>
> $4$ will be counted $2$ times (at $4,8$)
>
> ...

In general each factor $k$ is counted $\lfloor \frac{x}{k} \rfloor$ times.

This means we can rewrite our sum as

$$\sum_{k=1}^x  k \cdot \lfloor \frac{x}{k} \rfloor$$

We can set $ \lfloor \frac{x}{k} \rfloor=1$ to get our lower bound of $\frac{x(x+1)}{2}$

And we can set $ \lfloor \frac{x}{k} \rfloor= \frac{x}{k}$ to get our upper bound of $x^2$

Comment: Wow, thank you!

Comment: No problem the question was pretty fun to figure out.

Comment: However $x^2$ is not the tightest bound.

Comment: Is there a better one?